# bash Outputting invalid option

Tags: linux, bash, switch-statement, optional-parameters

Say I have the following script to handle options:

```
while getopts dsf opts 2>/dev/null
do
    case $opts in
    d) echo "d";;
    s) echo "s";;
    \?) echo "Error: An invalid option [?] was entered.";
        exit 1;;
    esac
done
```

I want to replace the [?] with the invalid switch I entered. 
So if I enter

```
./myscript -z //output: Error: An invalid option [-z] was entered.
```

How would I catch that invalid switch? Using my $opts variable displays a question mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `help getopts`:

> ```
> getopts reports errors in one of two ways.  If the first character
> of OPTSTRING is a colon, getopts uses silent error reporting.  In
> this mode, no error messages are printed.  If an invalid option is
> seen, getopts places the option character found into OPTARG.
> ```

Comment: man, info , help are always a good place to start before asking a question :)